# How to extract components of a disorganized string variable in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have a text variable showing patient prescription that looks quite messy like this:

---

```
PatientRx

 ACETAZOLAMIDE        250MG TABLET- 100  
ADAPALENE + BENZOYL  0.1% + 2.5% GEL-..    
ADRENALINE/EPIPEN    300MCG/0.3ML INJ..  
ALENDRONATE + COLECA 70MG + 140MCG TA..    
 ALLOPURINOL          100MG TABLET- 100  
ALUM HYDROX + MAG HY 250+120+120MG/5M..  
AMILORIDE + HYDROCHL 5MG + 50MG HCL T..
```

---

While I haven't looked through all these values, some patterns may arise:

- Often times there are more than one drugs and they are separated, for example by space and forward slash.
- Drugs are also be separated with plus sign. But plus sign is also used between doses.
- The rule related to space is very arbitrary, both at the beginning and in the middle of entry.

How can I extract only the names of the drugs into new variables? New variables should look like this:

```
Newvar1           Newvar2  
ACETAZOLAMIDE  
ADAPALENE         BENZOYL  
ADRENALINE        EPIPEN  
ALENDRONATE       COLECA
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some would reach first for regular expressions, which you might indeed need for the full problem. In addition note `moss` as installed by `ssc install moss`.

But it seems easiest, given the information in the example here, which is all we have to go on, to look for the position of the first numeric digit 0 to 9 and then parse what goes before. I don't know whether drug names ever contain numeric digits.

```
clear 
input str40 sandbox 
" ACETAZOLAMIDE        250MG TABLET- 100"  
"ADAPALENE + BENZOYL  0.1% + 2.5% GEL-"    
" ADRENALINE/EPIPEN    300MCG/0.3ML INJ"  
"ALENDRONATE + COLECA 70MG + 140MCG TA"    
" ALLOPURINOL          100MG TABLET- 100"  
"ALUM HYDROX + MAG HY 250+120+120MG/5M"  
" AMILORIDE + HYDROCHL 5MG + 50MG HCL T"
end 

gen wherenum = . 
quietly forval j = 0/9 { 
    replace wherenum = min(wherenum, strpos(sandbox, "`j'")) if strpos(sandbox, "`j'") 
}
gen drug = substr(sandbox, 1, wherenum - 1) 

split drug, parse(+ /) 

l drug?, sep(0) 

     +---------------------------+
     |         drug1       drug2 |
     |---------------------------|
  1. | ACETAZOLAMIDE             |
  2. |    ADAPALENE      BENZOYL |
  3. |    ADRENALINE      EPIPEN |
  4. |  ALENDRONATE       COLECA |
  5. |   ALLOPURINOL             |
  6. |  ALUM HYDROX       MAG HY |
  7. |    AMILORIDE     HYDROCHL |
     +---------------------------+
```